# e4 RCP Application: How do I disable window interaction with a Dialog?

Tags: eclipse-rcp, e4

I have a window with a table that allow users to add/edit and delete entries. The buttons will bring up a dialog window to perform the actions (Made with Window builder editor). However when the dialog window is up users can still interact with the table which could prove problematic. How can I "disable" interaction with the table window until the dialog window is closed?

[image]

Dialog class

```
 public class RoleEditDialog {
        Text txtRoleName;
        Spinner spnrEksLvl;
        Spinner spnrLvl;

        @PostConstruct
        public void postConstruct(Composite parent) {
            parent.setLayout(null);

            Group group = new Group(parent, SWT.BORDER);
            group.setText("Role");
            group.setBackground(SWTResourceManager.getColor(SWT.COLOR_WIDGET_LIGHT_SHADOW));
            group.setBounds(29, 83, 236, 164);

            Label label = new Label(group, SWT.NONE);
            label.setText("Role Name");
            label.setBackground(SWTResourceManager.getColor(SWT.COLOR_WIDGET_LIGHT_SHADOW));
            label.setBounds(8, 30, 66, 14);

            txtRoleName = new Text(group, SWT.BORDER);
            txtRoleName.setBounds(74, 27, 152, 20);

            Label label_1 = new Label(group, SWT.NONE);
            label_1.setText("EKS Level");
            label_1.setBackground(SWTResourceManager.getColor(SWT.COLOR_WIDGET_LIGHT_SHADOW));
            label_1.setBounds(8, 67, 59, 14);

            spnrEksLvl = new Spinner(group, SWT.BORDER);
            spnrEksLvl.setBounds(74, 64, 152, 20);

            spnrLvl = new Spinner(group, SWT.BORDER);
            spnrLvl.setBounds(74, 101, 152, 20);

            Label label_2 = new Label(group, SWT.NONE);
            label_2.setText("Level");
            label_2.setBackground(SWTResourceManager.getColor(SWT.COLOR_WIDGET_LIGHT_SHADOW));
            label_2.setBounds(8, 104, 54, 14);

            Label label_3 = new Label(parent, SWT.NONE);
            label_3.setText("Role Administration");
            label_3.setFont(SWTResourceManager.getFont("Lucida Bright", 19, SWT.BOLD));
            label_3.setBounds(10, 10, 259, 29);

            Label label_4 = new Label(parent, SWT.NONE);
            label_4.setText("New/Update Role");
            label_4.setBounds(97, 38, 93, 15);      
        }

    }
```

Handler class to open dialog

```
public class OpenEditRoleHandler {
    @Inject
    EModelService modelService;
    @Inject
    MApplication application;

    @Execute
    public void execute(MPart part) 
    {
        RoleController roleController = new RoleController();
        if(part!=null)
        {
            RolesFrame rolesFrame = (RolesFrame) part.getObject(); 
            int selecRow = rolesFrame.table.getSelectionIndex();
            if(selecRow!=-1)
            {
                RightController rightController = new RightController();

                //Dialog
                modelService.find("ats_usermanagement_rcp.dialog.RoleAdmin", application).setToBeRendered(true);
                //Dialog part (I have more than one part so depending on if Add/Edit was selected the appropriate part would be rendered)
                modelService.find("ats_usermanagement_rcp.part.RoleEditDialog", application).setToBeRendered(true);     

                Role selectedRole = roleController.getRole((long) Integer.parseInt(rolesFrame.table.getItem(selecRow).getText(0)));

                MPart editPart = (MPart) modelService.find("ats_usermanagement_rcp.part.RoleEditDialog", application);
                RoleEditDialog editRole = (RoleEditDialog) editPart.getObject();

                editRole.txtRoleName.setText(selectedRole.getRolename());
                editRole.spnrLvl.setSelection(selectedRole.getLevel());
                editRole.spnrEksLvl.setSelection(selectedRole.getEksLevel());   
            }   
        }       
    }       
}
```

Comment: Dialogs normally block interaction with the rest of the app. What styles is the dialog using? Are there any calls to `setBlockOnOpen` or `setShellStyle`? Show us an [mcve]

Comment: If using the style hint [`SWT.MODELESS`](https://help.eclipse.org/2018-09/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/swt/SWT.html#MODELESS`), remove it.

Comment: Ok I am pretty darn new to RCP and quite honestly have no idea what either of you are referring to.  I have been defining E4 dialogs in the application model in the "Windows and Dialogs" section of a the main application by adding a "Dialog" with the bounds of the dialog, then adding a part to it under "Controls" where I enter the dialog class. I then get a reference to it and set DialogPart.setToBeRendered(true) to make it "Pop up".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't really what is traditionally known as a Dialog - it is another part opening in a separate window. e4 doesn't really have good support for dialogs done using the Application.e4xmi. Most dialogs are done using the JFace `Dialog` class (`org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.Dialog`) and aren't in the Application.e4xmi.

You may be able to adjust the behaviour of the window by overriding the window style using the `styleOverride` (see [here](http://blog.vogella.com/2014/03/17/using-eclipse-application-model-persisted-state-to-specify-the-swt-stylebits/)) to specify the `SWT.APPLICATION_MODAL` flag. The override value for a dialog would be

```
styleOverride 68720
```

`68720` is the numeric value of the `SWT.DIALOG_TRIM | SWT.APPLICATION_MODAL | SWT.MAX | SWT.RESIZE` flags.